# NSFetchedResultsController return no data when it should

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a one **Room** entity to many **Message** entity releationship.
I use this FRC to fetch all the message in one room:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(rid == %@) AND (status >= 0)", _room];
_fetchControllerForHistory = [Message MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"serverDatetime,index" ascending:YES withPredicate:predicate groupBy:nil delegate:self];
```

It worked fine for the last few months,but after I update the app to use the new version of MagicalRecord,the problem appear.

I guess there is something wrong with my new fetch data from server code,
it now looks like this:

```
dispatch_async(retrieve_queue(), ^{
    ASIHTTPRequest *roomRequest = //code to genrate the request;
    [roomRequest startSynchronous];
    if (!roomRequest.error)
    {
        [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
            // code to parse the data
        }];
    }
});
```

After the fetch finish,every room will have at least on message.
But the FRC just not return any result even if the is one message in that room and the status is > 0.

```
NSLog(@"%i,%i",_room.mids.count, self.fetchControllerForHistory.fetchedObjects.count);
1,0
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're omitting all the relevant source code; you say that the problem appeared when upgrading to the latest MagicalRecord release, but then your guess is that your data retrieval code is the culprit. How do you actually create your request? What data are you receiving? How do you parse it?

Comment: The parse code is omitted because I think it's unrelevant. I just confuse that `_room.mids` can get result but the FRC get nothing.